# How to find out if a tile is being covered by a polygon?

Tags: map, geometry

Given a (intersecting) polygon, I'd like find out which tiles are being covered by the polygon.

**Example**:

[image: example]

**Details**:

- Tiles are square, 1 unit wide/high
- The grid begins in (0,0)
- The corners of the polygon can have floating point coordinates (i.e. 3.433, 5.234)
- In general, an edge of the polygon might be as long as 1000 - 10000 tiles

I tried to iterate over all tiles and check whether they are in the polygon, however as I have to iterate over 10000² tiles it takes a quite a long time.

I'm interested in a solution which allows me to quickly answer "Is tile (x,y) covered by the polygon?" without recomputing everything from scratch for each question.

Any solution/approach/pseudo-code/hint which leads me to a correct solution will be accepted.

Comment: Shrink wrap it, perhaps a modified https://www.cs.sfu.ca/~haoz/teaching/projects/cmpt469/0501/shrink_wrap/whole.html that pays attention to the grid size you've chosen?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Is the size of your tiles fixed? Is the orientation and position of the grid given, or is it arbitrary? Please clarify.

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: @DocBrown: I'd like to apologize for my unclear question. I added some further details, please let me know when something remains unclear...

Comment: @gnat Unfortunately, I couldn't find a solution better than just iterating over all tiles.

Comment: How are you determining if a tile is overlapped by the polygon now?  Is this real-time rendering?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you want to do polygon rasterization, where your "pixels" are your grid elements.

An approach I would try (as chances are you will find ready-to-use algorithms to do that), is to use an in-memory rasterizer (e.g. Cairo), adjusting the filtering (and of course the coordinates of your polygons so they are expressed in grid units).

You could alternatively roll your own using existing algorithms.
For instance:

- [split the polygon into its convex parts](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/60212/partitioning-a-polygon-into-convex-parts)
- draw each polygon's outline (more precise: each convex part's outline) with [Bresenham's line algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm)
- fill the holes (which should be easy since you are working with convex polygons)

For step 2, if you want to cover all pixels, see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381269/line-rasterisation-cover-all-pixels-regardless-of-line-gradient).

Comment: +1, I think especially if the raster resolution is high compared to the polygon size this approach will work much better than my suggestion.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, is there an easy way to avoid that tiles crossed near a corner are not being painted? E.g. in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Bresenham.svg 4 pixels are white even though the line crosses the pixels.

Comment: Look up simplices and simplicial complexes and Voronoi diagrams and their duals.

Comment: The coverage problem was solved on SO - I edited the question to include the link.